# iPad does not show in xcode

Tags: xcode, ipad, xcode4, ios5

I have just updated my iPad with iOS 5 and now when I am connecting my device to my macbook it does not appear in xcode. It used to appear in xcode earlier when I had not updated my iPad but now it just does not show in xcode. can someone please help me?

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't knew after updation of os in iPad i had t again make changes through Organiser and click on button use for development. I just did it and it started working. :):)

Answer (score 0):

there is an option called use for development.You have to do that now.